# Does Eloquent ORM(laravel 5) take care of SQL injection?

Tags: laravel, pdo, orm, eloquent, sql-injection

I couldn't find it online, but does Eloquent ORM take care of SQL injection like PDO prepared statements do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per your question all the eloquent queries are taken care of for
SQL injection, because they use the PDO driver in core. So you
don't have to worry, but the input are stored as they are so you might
want to sanitize as per your application's needs (HTML formatting,
etc.)

Comment: This should be the very straight forward and concise answer.

Answer (score 30):

**No framework "takes care of" SQL injection.**

*You* take care of SQL injection.

A framework may provide methods of doing that conveniently, but you still have to use the methods consistently.

For example, you should use query parameters instead of concatenating variables into your SQL expressions.

---

Re your comment:

Eloquent has methods like `whereRaw()` which allow you to write any expression you want. Here's [an example from the Eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent):

```
$users = User::whereRaw('age > ? and votes = 100', [25])->get();
```

If you use this `?` syntax for parameters, and pass the values as the array argument following, then yes, you can safely depend on Eloquent to use parameterization.

But it's *not* accurate to say "Eloquent takes care of SQL injection" because that leads some naive developers to think that you can do unsafe things like this:

```
$users = User::whereRaw("age > {$_GET['age']} and votes = 100")->get();
```

And they mistakenly believe that Eloquent can magically fix it for you. **This is not true.**

Every ORM provides safe ways of combining application variables into the query, but also provides ways developers can circumvent that. They have to provide those methods, because there are always parts of queries that cannot be parameterized.

That's what I mean when I say it's up to you to use the ORM properly, and avoid unsafe code.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the question.  If I use Eloquent for my queries, passing in raw variables(w/o taking care of SQL injection myself) will Eloquent take care of it behind the scenes.  AS the other answer said, yes it does.  GB.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, very clear and well written.

Comment: _If_ you use Eloquent models to do all operations, and do things the "Eloquent way" (meaning NEVER use functions with the word "raw" in them; IE if you are writing _any_ SQL code, you are doing it wrong), Eloquent will take care of injection because it uses parameterized statements. However the onus is on you to test and try to break it since you never know if someone will get a pull request by where parameterized statements are somehow bypassed in an edge case. Never trust anything until you've tested it

Comment: @user356540, The same caveats apply to any ORM in any language. They're great when you use them properly. If you bypass the ORM methods, you're on your own and you're responsible for writing SQL code securely.

Comment: @PauloFreitas I guess you also didn't read the question properly. the questioner is asking about using Eloquent ORM and not Raw query.

Comment: @AmitShah The `whereRaw()` function is part of the Eloquent ORM.

Comment: Well before coming here, I was sure for that I am just looking for the non-sql (raw) query syntax handling behavior by eloquent. I must sure the original questioner had the same meaning. because it's apparent that for the raw sql queries, we can not hold Eloquent responsible.

Comment: @AmitShah Yes, that's exactly the point of my answer.

Comment: @BillKarwin you did great job by answering in detail. but not addressing the question yet at the same time. `raw` functions can cause these SQL injection issues that is already considered. so not asking about how it works. the question here was other than raw if we don't use sql syntax and just use plain eloquent's internal query building mechanism. 
Thanks again for the detailed answer but I would vote for the @msonowal. to the point and concise.

Comment: @AmitShah The question did not specify which part of Eloquent to be used. They just asked if Eloquent "took care of" SQL injection. I pointed out that one can use Eloquent but still write unsafe code. You can vote for whomever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but the onus is still on you to validate the data coming in, and escape data coming out, as prepared statements are only part of the picture.

As a side note - I don't think dependency injection means what you think it means. Laravel does dependency injection via its service container, but DI is actually a good thing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)